# saving indexes of strings in lua tables (arrays or dictionary table?)

Tags: indexing, lua, lua-table

So I have quite a dilemma. I have a code that reads a certain msg, for example:

```
m.content:sub(1,8) == 'Loot of ' then
```

reads:

```
01:50 Loot of a starving wolf: a dirty fur, a salad, 2 pancakes, 60 gold
```

Now  I'm trying to make it insert into a table. The problem I have so far is that I can't make it count the type of string and compare it in the table to add its index.

For example:

```
t = {dirty fur="quantity of msgs that show this",insert a new msg="how many times haves appear}
```

What I have working so far is:

```
foreach newmessage m do
m.content:sub(1,8) == 'Loot of ' then
```

and then I'm just lost. I don't know how to create this table; it should be local, I believe, but the main problem I have with this is that I don't want to print it in pairs, I want to call the values from 1 to #table, in the order they were inserted. That's where my pain starts.

I want something like:

```
table msgs = {spear='100',something='2', ovni='123'}
```

so when I get this table (which I still can't make), I can call the same table for another function, that well I want to call table."xmsg" = quantity. I hope someone understands what I'm asking.

```
function loot()
foreach newmessage m do
        if m.type == MSG_INFO and m.content:sub(1,8) == 'Loot of ' then
        local content = (m.content:match('Loot of .-: (.+)')):token(nil,', ')
        for i,j in ipairs(content) do
       return content
         end
      end
   end
end
```

return msgs of this function :

```
{"3 gold coins"}
{"3 gold coins"}
{"nothing"}
{"6 gold coins", "a hand axe"}
{"12 gold coins", "a hand axe"}
```

Comment: Can you rewrite your example with real cases? It's difficult to know what you are talking about if you write "asdf". Then you mention "spear" and "ovni", but those don't appear previouwly.

Comment: You may want to make a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to explain yourself better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TEST_LOG = [[
01:50 Loot of a starving wolf: a dirty fur, a large melon, a cactus
02:20 Loot of a giant: a large melon, an axe
03:30 You are on fire! Not really, this is just a test message
04:00 Loot of a starving wolf: a dirty fur, a tooth, a bundle of hair
04:00 Loot of a starving wolf: a dirty fur, a tooth, an axe
]]

ENEMY_LOOT_COUNTS = {}
LOOT_COUNTS = {}

for line in string.gmatch(TEST_LOG, "([^\n]+)\n") do
    local time, msg = string.match(line, "(%d%d:%d%d) (.+)$")
    if msg and msg:sub(1, 8) == "Loot of " then
        local enemy_name, contents = string.match(msg, "^Loot of a ([^:]+): (.+)$")
        local enemy_t = ENEMY_LOOT_COUNTS[enemy_name]
        if not enemy_t then
            enemy_t = {}
            ENEMY_LOOT_COUNTS[enemy_name] = enemy_t
        end
        local items = {}
        for item_name in string.gmatch(contents, "an? ([^,]+)") do
            items[#items+1] = item_name
            enemy_t[item_name] = (enemy_t[item_name] or 0)+1
            LOOT_COUNTS[item_name] = (LOOT_COUNTS[item_name] or 0)+1
        end
    else
        -- you can handle other messages here if you want
    end
end

for enemy_name, loot_counts in pairs(ENEMY_LOOT_COUNTS) do
    local s = "Enemy "..enemy_name.." dropped: "
    for item_name, item_count in pairs(loot_counts) do
        s = s..item_count.."x "..item_name..", "
    end
    print(s)
end

do
    local s = "Overall: "
    for item_name, item_count in pairs(LOOT_COUNTS) do
        s = s..item_count.."x "..item_name..", "
    end
    print(s)
end
```

I wanted to write a long answer to accompany this code, but I don't have the time right now, sorry.
I'll do it later.

Comment: i have that code that returns these strings, so theres no need to read the time or the creatures, now my problem its that i couldnt make it to work in the piece of code you gave me, so my question its how can i include your type of counter to count these messages

{"3 gold coins"}
{"3 gold coins"}
{"nothing"}
{"6 gold coins", "a hand axe"}
{"12 gold coins", "a hand axe"}